# iAd/Admob mediation NEVER works

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, iad

Did I set it up correctly?

I downloaded the SDK from google's admob site I also installed the libAdapteriAd into Xcode. In build settings in linker flags i put -ObjC. Then in Library Search paths there is The google SDK, and libAdapteriAd together separated by " " , " ". Did  I do this right? I also set up iAd cpm higher than Admob cpm. No matter what mediation doesn't work. If an AdMob ad pops up first iAd NEVER appears. If iAd pops up first AdMob never appears. I don't know why. Maybe i set up mediation wrong with the above steps?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you should consider to try out Appodeal http://appodeal.com/+signup They have Admob and several others in there mediation process and you don´t need to register for every single network. They pay 7-9$ eCPM, seems to be really optimized